# cache and persist datasets

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I'd like to use an org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet object several times:

- print the number of rows using count(),
- writing to a neo4j database,
- converting to a Gelly graph object,
- etc.

With each of these actions, Flink completely recalculates the value of the DataSet instead of caching it. I can't find any cache() or persist() function like in Spark.

This does have a huge impact on my application with ~1.000.000 data with many joins / coGroup usages etc.: The runtime seems to increase by a factor of 3, which is several hours! So how can I cache or persist datasets and reduce the runtime significantly?

I'm using the newest Flink release 1.3.2, and Scala 2.11.

Example:

```
package dummy

import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.graph.scala.Graph
import org.apache.flink.graph.{Edge, Vertex}
import org.apache.logging.log4j.scala.Logging

object Trials extends Logging {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    // some dataset which could be huge in reality
    val dataSet = env.fromElements((1, 436), (2, 235), (3, 67), (4, 51), (5, 15), (6, 62), (7, 155))

    // some complex joins, coGroup functions etc.
    val joined = dataSet.cross(dataSet).filter(tuple => (tuple._1._2 + tuple._2._2) % 7 == 0)

    // log the number of rows --> performs the join above
    logger.info(f"results contains ${joined.count()} rows")

    // convert to Gelly graph format
    val graph = Graph.fromDataSet(
      dataSet.map(nodeTuple => new Vertex[Long, Long](nodeTuple._1, nodeTuple._2)),
      joined.map(edgeTuple => new Edge[Long, String](edgeTuple._1._1, edgeTuple._2._1, "someValue")),
      env
    )

    // do something with the graph
    logger.info("get number of vertices")
    val numberOfVertices = graph.numberOfVertices()
    logger.info("get number of edges")
    val numberOfEdges = graph.numberOfEdges() // --> performs the join again!

    logger.info(f"the graph has ${numberOfVertices} vertices and ${numberOfEdges} edges")
  }

}
```

Required libs: log4j-core, log4j-api-scala_2.11, flink-core, flink-scala_2.11, flink-gelly-scala_2.10

Comment: Can you post an example of one of the the actions and DataSets that you'd like to cache?

Comment: Added a simplified version of my code

Comment: Have you found a solution to this question? I have the same issue

Comment: We only found https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/batch/#distributed-cache after some time, but we didn't try it anymore. As far as I see, it's only for static data sources, not for results of operations like join / cross / filter / etc.
Maybe the solution would be to use some NoSQL database or queue in the middle, and read from that in several other Flink processes... Though I don't really like that idea because of the read/write overhead ;-/
When someone knows how to do it, I'd appreciate to find some guidance here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, in case you need to perform multiple operations on the same stream, it's worth using the side outputs - https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html.

Once you have performed some complex joins, coGroup functions etc. and got a `joined` dataset, you can collect the values to different side outputs - the one which will later on calculate count, the other which will do the other job.

Comment: Sounds good.. Can't try it as I changed to other projects, but seems to solve the problem.